# Using protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I want to use protocols. I have a collection view and collection view cells which belongs to this collection view. I have a button in this cell. I want to call a method in collectionview class (not cell class) when user taps to this button.

I am defining my **cell class** with following code:

```
protocol testPro {
    func replyClicked()
}

class MessageGalleryViewControllerCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var test1: testPro?

    // ...
}
```

Then when user taps to button system calling following method in **cell class**.

```
func replyAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    test1?.replyClicked()

}
```

And My **collection view class**:

```
class ReceivedPhotosViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, testPro {

    func replyClicked() {
        print("clicked")
    }
}
```

But I can't see any log like "clicked". So it is not working. Where is the problem?

Comment: Where are you setting the cell's `testPro`?  You need to set it back to the view controller in `cellForItemAtindexPath` after you instantiate the cell.

Comment: Can you explain more? Also please check this:http://prntscr.com/azjkdd

Comment: It worked,  if you add this as an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning your `test1` to your cell.  In your `cellForItemAtindexPath`, put `cell.test1 = self` after instantiating the cell.